# Dynamically loaded images not displaying properly in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm creating a banner advertisement in Flash.  It pulls all information from an XML file.  Images for each product are also loaded externally.  Everything is working fine except for 1 thing.

I have an image separator i'm using as a background for each product container to lend a bit of separation to each product.  But when I try to add it using code it's only added to the last item.  Doesn't matter if it's 10 items or 2 items...it's only being added to the last one and i'm not sure why.  Anyways, i've zipped up the associated files and put it on my webserver.   I'm using the Tweener class and have included that in the archive as well.  Any help in the matter would be much appreciated.

Here's a link to the archive : [Project Files](http://www.grantandrew.com/testing/flash/XML/XMLad.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i have previous version of flash, and cannot open the fla file. But my guess is that you creating the image separator object and than using addChild add it to all 10 items. And it start to add this (one) object in turn to every item. And finally it become a child of the last item. Is this is you problem. you just need to create different separators for every item.

Comment: In short: `addChild` will remove the *child* from it's previous *father* and add it to the new one. The method WILL NOT duplicate the *child*.

Comment: @NemoStein thanks sometimes it's hard to translate your thoughts into words)

Comment: thanks for the comments, i re-jigged things and have it working now.